# Upvotes stopping just before 10, 25

Tags: discussion

[I am just curious & discussion only question]

I was checking my summary page & seeing a pattern of votes stoppage just before some milestone (badge like Nice Question, Good Question, Nice Answer).

[image]

Is this intentional - people stop voting further because they think otherwise about awarding badge?

Or should I wait for it to reach certain vote count before accepting answers? (as people may hit more towards unanswered questions)

Comment: @Carcigenicate am searching for that discussion..

Comment: @ArunVinoth: There are not sufficient data points in your posts to constitute a "pattern".

Comment: @NicolBolas hmm maybe some SEDE query will show it

Comment: So where did all my badges come from then? No, I highly doubt that there is an actual pattern here. Just because you found one page that lists a few posts close to badges does not a pattern make.

Comment: ok, am going to upvote whichever is 9 or 24 or 99 as they are eligible for that +1 atleast

Comment: I did find handful, started with people commented here.. :) happy seeing badges that glittering in green :)

Comment: @ArunVinoth: vote on the content you come across naturally, don't seek out posts to vote on just to hand out badges.

Comment: @ArunVinoth: "*hmm maybe some SEDE query will show it*" You gather evidence *before* you decide there's a problem. You don't say "there's a problem", then expect other people to figure out if it really is a problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I care a lot about SE network content like you do. don't worry.. once in a while we have to think about next generation folks, their curiosity in this game, eagerness to reach half of the merits like others, etc who joined late in the party bcoz of their age purely, which many of the huge votebank people don't understand, as you cannot clearly see the challenge of getting some 1,2 votes these days

Comment: @NicolBolas I dint tag problem, but just discussion tag.. chill

Comment: @ArunVinoth: I joined the network 'late'. I know plenty of successful users that joined later. They do not need special treatment. Let *good content* speak for itself. Good content has no problems getting votes **no matter who wrote it**. Don't tell me I can't see 'the challenge', please.

Comment: It seems users are downrating based on the comments above.  However, per @Carcigenicate 's anecdotal answer, there may be some truth in what the op observed.  Granted, maybe the accusatory comments above poison the original post, but I find it interesting that there could be some truth in the thresholding he observed, at least per the anecdote.  I think where the post goes off the rails is when it comes to the accusatory comments.

Comment: @JasonR.Mick Two people's anecdotal experiences isn't data any more than one person's experiences are.  The question does nothing to demonstrate the existence of the behavior they're claiming is happening, nor is there anything showing thow, if true, it's a problem.  There's just nothing useful to discuss here.  If the OP does their research, maybe they'll *find* something worth discussing, but they haven't even gotten that far yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Haven't you been here since 2009? There are successful users who started late, but I don't think you're a good example.

Comment: @user2357112: my account was mostly dormant until mid 2012, see my central rep graph: https://stackexchange.com/users/35417/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation. By that time I was definitely a latecomer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt that they're voting the way they are to prevent you from getting a badge.

There was a post a while ago (that's proving very difficult to find) that discussed how voting tends to stop once the community "decides" that the score of a question/answer is adequate; even if that's not how voting is supposed to work.

I have to admit, I've done this before. I'll see a decent question, but because of when it was posted, it has like 10 up votes. I'll look it over, and think "it's good, but 10s getting a little excessive", and I won't vote for it. I know that's wrong, but I suspect that it's widespread. I have no evidence that it's commonplace, but if I've thought of voting this way before, I have my doubts that I'm the only one.

---

As an alternative explanation, it could also have to do with timing of the post, and who views it.

When you first post, your question will have a rush of activity from people browsing new questions, and they'll vote as they see fit. Once the rush dies down though, voting will slow, and eventually stop. Once you've been buried by new posts, the only people who will see your post after that are people browsing the tags of your question, or later, people who found your question on Google. If you use unpopular tags, and ask rarely searched questions, your question's final score would be whatever it was when the attention died down.

---

Or, it's could be because the score had some artificial significance. I have a challenge on PPCG to convert times between 12 and 24 formats. It got stuck on a score of 24 for a while. I can only speculate why that's where it stopped, but it was pretty obvious to me at the time.

Comment: really appreciate your openness.. thumbs up..

Comment: In my eyes the very nature of Stack Overflow makes it near impossible for people to start to develop this sort of behavioural patterns; to do that you'd need to have more opportunity to socially interact with each other, something that Stack Overflow by design makes difficult for you to do. I'm sure some people vote as described, but they can't influence the masses to follow their lead.

Comment: @Gimby I put quotes around "decide" because I think it's probably a "fuzzy decision". Everyone likely has an idea in their head of what score a post should have, roughly, based on previous posts they've seen. Even if not everyone agrees exactly what score a post should have, once the score reaches a certain point, the rate of voting will start to decrease. This is all assuming that this phenomenon exists.

Comment: @Gimby We do occasionally get someone asking on Meta if it's OK to vote counter to what they feel a question deserves in terms of quality in order to make the overall score what they think it should be. Usually they want to up vote a post they know is bad because they think the score is *too* negative. So there are at least a few users voting based on the existing score instead of just on quality and usefulness.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the downvotes on this post strike me as odd, given that your post basically confirms what he's observing to some extent is true (albeit not as personal as he feared).  Why do you think the op's post got downrated so severely?

Comment: Ah, scanning the comments, I think they've poisoned an otherwise interesting discussion by getting overly personal / accusatory.  Makes more sense now.

Comment: @JasonR.Mick I think it's being downvoted because he's assuming malicious intent. I can't imagine that the community as a whole appreciates that. And I don't think my answer confirms his suspicions. He's suspecting it's because people want to prevent him from getting a badge. I'm saying that there may be arbitrary thresholds that people vote to, but it's not for ill-intent, or based on badges.

Comment: Right... to be clear I meant "confirms his suspicions" in the sense that there's some logic (per your comment) which causes people to pause at up voting if the vote pushes a post beyond those thresholds.  I definitely didn't mean to infer that you validated the more accusatory part alleging a personal attack.  Just noting that perhaps that one passing sentence could be overlooked were it not for his followups below which made the discussion overly toxic.

Comment: @BSMP indeed but at least the cases that do end up on meta will get a good education about how voting is supposed to work :)

Comment: And that's why we should implement Reddits voting system... *just kidding*.